# One-click way of disabling Windows sleep timers

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, power-management

I am looking for a **tiny shortcut icon** or **small portable exe** which runs in the system tray and gives a **one-click way of disabling/enabling the display turn-off and system sleep timers in Windows 7**.

I used to own a Thinkpad, it had a Presentation mode just for this purpose, but it modified the CPU policies as well as other things, since it was a power profile. I am looking for something which just turns off these timers temporarily but is not a separate power profile.

A .bat file with some powercfg command line is perfect for me, but I don't know the depths of powercfg.

Do you know any such utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Don't Sleep](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep). It's a tiny (36 KB) portable application that applies temporary rules to your power saving settings. It runs in the system tray. I've been using it for a long time and I really like it.

[image: screeny]

Comment: Wow, it looks perfect! 36K, crazy!